# FMJ, JMF civil, about a bloody headache

Tags: tags

I am trying to write a java application that uses the web cam and I am just desperate. It feels just like mission impossible.

I have two webcams. They are recognized by Ubuntu as follows

```
ls /dev/vi*

/dev/video0  /dev/video1

ls /dev/v4l/by-id

usb-0471_0310_0169000099000000-video-index0
usb-Fujitsu_Siemens_Computers_FSC_WebCam_130-video-index0
```

they work perfectly well with any software

vlc, cheese webcam... you name it

but with java... (O M G...)

after a week of try and fail...

JMF: does not recognize these two cams, no matter what I tried.
FMJ (which seems to use civil) recognize only video0 after having installed avformat libraries

but

- I can't add any device in the registry application clicking on the add device button, nothing happens
- in the fmjstudio, selecting video0, I get

> unknown or unsupported format: 1448695129

anyway, in all cases, I don't see how I could write something serious and usable by any kind of user who does not know how/want to install libraries and start fighting with additional packages installation

these libraries are just pure crap

a simple cat command will dump the content of the webcam stream

so does anyone knows any serious alternative to those crappy libraries?